When talking about a broken device, would there be any difference between: "I will get it working." and "I will get it to work."
Someone is trying to use a device and realizes that it is not working. So he says:
I will try and get it working. ITV-dental crisis (see:4:00-4:12)
The structure "get it working" reminded of a similar structure with similar meaning (causative): "get it to work."
Grammatically, they both seem to have a causative meaning, however I am not sure whether it would be correct if the speaker said:
"I will try and get it to work." instead of "......get it working."?

I think it's the same as I like working / to work (or love / prefer / ...). Basically, a stylistic choice that doesn't [normally?] affect meaning. In your example context, I'm quite sure initial I will try and is syntactically irrelevant. You could just as well compare the two imperatives "Get it to work!" and "Get it working!", or "I want it working / to work".

I'm not American. 'try and' seems off to me. I thought the correct form would be "I will try to get it working."

It's beginning to look like you've selected an incorrect answer.

@Astralbee The lemmings went over the cliff with this: "Get it to work" could sound like a one-off thing". That is not so. And I gave an example explaining why that is not so.

try and [action] verb is common in English. See Ngrams and enter: try and finish, choose British English.

@lambie Ngrams only show frequency. That doesn't account for context. How often a word is used does not indicate whether or not it is being used correctly.

@Astralbee HarryH says "try and [verb]" is not British English. That's wrong. You try it with search term: try and *  Look at all those verbs. Personally, I dislike ngrams but it is useful here. Those cannot all be wrong.

@Lambie I haven't said anything is wrong! Google ngrams uses Google books as its source. Everything is published so ought to be a credible source and have no mistakes. So it's never a comparison of what is right or wrong - only a comparison of how often correctly used words or short phrases are used. How is that useful here?

@Lambie {"'Get it to work' could sound like a one-off thing". That is not so.} With that phrase on its own, you are correct here. But when it's placed in contrast with "get it working," Astralbee's distinction does appear.

"I'm not American. 'try and' seems off to me. I thought the correct form would be "I will try to get it working." Not so. Ngram search for British English: try and *

A device (or motor or machine) is broken, so we say to the person with the broken device:

I'll get it working again. [because it is not working now]

OR

I'll get it to work. [because it doesn't work now]

Dialogue:
John: My computer seems to be on the blink. Can you get it to work again?
Billy: Yes, I can get it working again quickly.
OR
John: My computer seems to be on the blink. Can you get it working again?
Billy: Yes, I can get it to work again for you.
So, either can be used. There is not any essential difference between those two dialogues.
For example:
I have a new dishwasher and I push the on button and it does not start running, and I say to the repair person: Can you get it to work? He answers: Sure thing, I'll get it working in no time.
If a new machine, device, motor etc. has not worked when you turn it on the first time, you cannot get it to work. Here, we wouldn't usually say: get it working in our description of the problem.
However, the second one has an additional meaning.
to get something to work is not just about devices, motors, etc.
A relationship can be said to not work. For example, you've been disagreeing with someone about  your relationship for a while, so you might say:

We should make an effort and get it [the relationship] to work again?
OR
John doesn't think he can get his relationship with Ada to work again.


There's little difference in a superficial sense, but the implications of each one are quite distinct. And the "relationship" "meaning" here is simply a different application of the same meaning; it is not an additional meaning.

@user33113  Shorting the starter might get a car to work (simple present), and you can do that as many times as you want (repeatable). Getting the car working (present progressive/continuous), however, would involve replacing or rebuilding the starter. Superficially (on the face of it at this moment), they result in the same thing (the car is running now), but the implication of which one you say carries a different meaning concerning the future and ongoing state of the car.

@user33113 Relationships would follow exactly the same pattern that I described with the car. You can most definitely say "we should get it working again". The situation would be if a couple had a good relationship, broke up, but then one (or both) of them desired to fix the issue(s) and get back together to have a good continuing relationship like before. "We should get it to work again" would be used if they had a good relationship at some point, it turned sour for some reason, and now they want to fix that issue (but more issues might still come up later that could split them again).

"That user" is you, Lambie (note the ID), since apparently if I post your name itself with an @, it disappears from the beginning of the comment.

"Get it working", using the continuous tense, better suggests that you will restore something to working order so that it will go on working, perhaps autonomously. We use 'working' to describe the state of something (ie "*in working order").
"Get it to work" could sound like a one-off thing - for example, if you had an old car that is difficult to start, you might say "I'll try to get it to start", meaning a one-time effort to make it start the one time. But, if you said "I'll get it starting properly" that would mean you were going to fix the starting issue once and for all.
This is not meant to be a firm distinction - both could be fine in some contexts, but I certainly find "get it working" to be a more idiomatic and accurate way to refer to fixing or repairing something so that it is in working order..

I don't see this as a firm distinction, though. Get it to work seems fine to me for get it in working order.

@KateBunting I don't see it as a firm distinction either and have not claimed it to be such.

I'm not alone in thinking this: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-got-it-working-got-it-to-work.2314831/

Person 1: The car wasn't working. Did you get it to work like last time?  Person 2: Yes,I always get it to work when you ask me. /Not a one off/  ["Fortunately for them, there's no shortage of wrong answers here for them to find what they want to hear".] You should be more careful with  your comments.

@Lambie: Your example supports Astralbee's point. Person 1 is saying that the car is not in a continuous state of being operational, and Person 2 is saying that they have repeated one-off success in making the car run (as opposed to putting it in a state where it is unequivocally operational for everyone).

@RLH It amazes me the people one has never seen here show up and make comments like that. Astralbee said: Get it to work" could sound like a one-off thing. My example in my comment above shows that it is not a one-off thing. It is a repeated thing. One-off means once, not twice and this"I always get it to work when you ask me.=multiple times. Anything else now?

@Lambie: I'm sorry you can't see the distinction between a change into a continuous state of being and a one-off action that can be repeated.

@RLH one-off Merriam Webster
adjective
Synonyms of one-off
1
: limited to a single time, occasion, or instance : ONE-SHOT
one-off gigs
a one-off payment
2
: SINGULAR, UNIQUE
a one-off design

@Lambie: I can hire someone for a one-off job, and then the next week decide to hire them again for a one-off job. Even if I make a habit of doing so, it’s different from setting up a contract stating that I will hire them each week. Going back to the original point, there can be many (thousands or millions of) dollars difference between “I got the machine to work” [it did its task once and it produced a widget] or “I got the machine working” [it’s running and reliably/continuously producing widgets].

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
